# Chow countability argument

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, hilbert-schemes, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

I would like to know what the "Chow countability argument or HIlbert schemes countability argument" says in order to finish an exercise. Any reference will also be very useful :)!

Comment: Some context would be very useful for us to answer the question too.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "Chow countability argument" before.  Google seems confused as well. Where did you encounter it? (If I had to guess, it has something to do with the fact that Chow varieties/Hilbert schemes have countably many components. But this is just a guess.)